# Double memory allocation in C#. Bad?

Tags: c#, memory, garbage

Lets say I have next class:

```
class MyClass
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public List<string> Data = new List<string>();
}
```

I need to fill some list of `MyClass` instances in next way;

```
// member
private List<MyClass> m_instances = new List<MyClass>();

// some function

public void MyFunc()
{
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();

    for (/* something */)
    {
        instance.Id = "id1";
        instance.Data.Add("data1");

        if (/* something */)
        {
            m_instances.Add(instance);
            instance = new MyClass(); // (!!!!)to clear data
        }
    }
}
```

Will GC handle it in correct way?

P.S. I could not free properties manually because there are a lot of properties...

Comment: _"I need to feel "_ I hope you need to _fill_ some lists instead.

Comment: It is clumsy code that will get you in trouble.  Never fear gen#0 collections.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Yep. You are totally right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler to just move the object instantiation into the loop, at the top of the loop:

```
for (/* something */)
{
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    instance.Id = "id1";
    instance.Data.Add("data1");

    if (/* something */)
    {
        m_instances.Add(instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it does not clear the instance in the `List`. It will only create a new instance of `MyClass` and assign in to `instance`.

You have to set the instance itself to a different value, like this:

```
m_instances[index] = new MyClass();
```

Or

```
m_instances[m_instances.IndexOf(instance)] = new MyClass();
```

Comment: It is actually what I need. Just free temporary storage to have opportunity to use it again.

Comment: @user2706838 There's no such thing as "free temporary storage". Every initialized object is created separately on a heap. It doesn't matter if you'll use the same object reference or not. I don't think you understand what a reference type is.

Answer (score 2):

`instance = new MyClass(); // (!!!!)to clear data` - it's not clearing the data, it's constructing a new object. Just put `MyClass instance = new MyClass();` inside your loop. Even if you would do it the proper way

```
MyClass instance;
for (/* something */)
{
    if(something)
    {
        instance = new MyClass();
        instance.Id = "id1";
        instance.Data.Add("data1");
        m_instances.Add(instance);
    }
}
```

Then it would not matter, because compiler will generate the same code as if you would create and initialize the object inside the loop.